image feature fitting and measurement by OpenCV
I am doing some measurements on a droplet cap sitting on a limited surface in a avi video. I have two videos, one for a ellipse cap and one for the part beneath called NW. the main goal is to measure the length of the flat baseline where cap and the NW meet, tangent lines of the ellipse where the baseline intersects with ellipse fitted, and draw these line to visualize the quality of measurements. I have written the python code, but I do not understand why the two intersecions points are deviated somehow from where they actually intersec, and tangent lines deviate too. If you want, you can check my code and use it as reference, or you can write your own code and share it with me. We will see what is the difference that causes the problem. Here is my code and two videos. Thanks!
Notes: the coordinate might be reversed in case like in opencv (x,y) and numpy (row, colomn)
dropbox link for two videos and code I am using to produce the image below
cuurent result, the position of two intersection points in yellow not so accurate:


Please read [mre]. This is a lot of code, nobody is going to sift through that for you. I’m sure you can narrow down the issue better.

Thank you Cris. I understant. maybe it is better not to put the code here, probably starting from the video is good idea, because I think for the problem itself it is not difficult, but reading other people's code is difficult. I rephrase the problem
